# C#- cannot get values in statesSouth to populate in webgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

So i have gone through this more than a dozen times and I'm beyond frustrated. I can get some values to come up within the list of statesWest and statesEast but cannot get some values to come up within the list of statesSouth. I double checked that the code for state is reading legitimately as it appears in the list but am still not seeing it appear. Can someone please help me out with this. The end goal is to create regions based on the list selection. below is the code.

This is my model (Using ASP.NET MVC5)

```
private static string FindStateList(string stateCode)
    {
        var statesWest = new List<string> { "AK", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "HI", "IA", "ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "MI", "MN", "MO", "MT", "ND", "NE", "NM", "NV", "OH", "OK", "OR", "SD", "TX", "UT", "WA", "WI", "WY" };
        var statesEast = new List<string> { "CT", "DC", "DE", "KY", "MA", "MD", "ME", "NC", "NH", "NJ", "NY", "PA", "RI", "SC", "TN", "VA", "VT", "WV" };
        var statesSouth = new List<string> { "AL", "FL", "GA", "LA", "MS" };


        if (statesWest.Any(s => s.IndexOf(stateCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
        {
            return "W";
        }
        if (statesEast.Any(s => s.IndexOf(stateCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
        {
            return "E";
        }
        if (statesSouth.Any(s => s.IndexOf(stateCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
        {
            return "S";
        }
        return "";
    }
public string AmTerritory { get { return FindStateList(State.Code); } }
```

This is my view row:

```
    grid.Column("", "AMT", item => item.AmTerritory, "quotepipe-amterritory"),
```

When I run the program this is what it looks like:

[image: output obtained]

Comment: Also note the values are being pulled from a SQL database table